# Null check with Long does not work when extracted from JSON using GSON Library

Tags: json, null, gson, long-integer

I have a Data class as below

```
Class Data { 
    private Long check; 
    private Long cost; 
}
```

My jsonString looks like

```
"data": { "cost": 5 }
```

when I do

```
Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
```

and I check for null for check like below

```
if (data.check == null) {//print error message}
```

It does not work. the statements at {//print error message} are not executed. Any idea whats happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "It does not work."?

Comment: The statements at  {//do something here} are not executed.

Comment: Shouldn't it be if (data.check != null)? Then you'd want to use it

Comment: no. I actually want to print an error message when check is null

Comment: That string doesn't look like valid JSON. Are you sure that's the input? Can you create a [stripped-down, minimal example version of your program that we can run and that demonstrates the error when we run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The JSON works file. if I check the value of cost, I get 5.

Comment: If you want to execute a test to see if your line executes you could set your `data.check = null` before you call your if statement. This would simulate it not getting parsed correctly

Comment: What is the value of data.check? Print it out.

Comment: It prints out blank. But if I do a data.check.longvalue or data.check.toString, it gives a NPE

Comment: @MrEngineer13 tried data.setCheck(null) before the if statement. Still didn't work. Weird

Comment: Instead of using the null check what you could do as an alternative is to set a default value like so `Long check = Long.MIN_VALUE` then check `if (data.check == Long.MIN_VALUE) {}`

Comment: I can, but I am just curious as to why isn't this working. Creating a sample code right now

Answer (score 0):

If you have a json sample such as:

```
{
  "data": {
    "cost": 5
  }
}
```

it means you have an object which has an inner object named as data. So you have to define the inner pojo(`Data`) and its holder pojo(i.e `DataHolder`):

```
class DataHolder {
    private Data data;
}

class Data { 
    private Long check; 
    private Long cost; 
}
```

Then you can deserialize your json string to a java instance:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

String jsonString = "{\"data\": { \"cost\": 5 }}";
DataHolder dataHolder = gson.fromJson(jsonString, DataHolder.class);
```